# CodeIgniter: My CSS file in my view not working

Tags: php, css, codeigniter

hallo I am running CodeIgniter 3.0.6 and this is my directory structure:

```
/application
/assets
   /js
     /mycss.css
/system
```

My default controller is loading this file in the `index.php` just fine but when i load another page, the whole page loads afresh but although this file is getting loaded, it is not doing what i want it to do. When i view sourcepage, the links are OK. What could be the problem. I am using `base_url('assets/js/mycss')` to load it

To put it simpler i have my default controller as welcome. In the `index()` method of this controller i have `$this->load->view('template/index')`. This works fine. Now if i load the same page in another method, `uniserve()`, in the same controller my css file does not do what i want it to do (my page layout is distorted) but all other css files are doing well. What is the problem here. Kindly help.

This link provide exact problem and exact code but my `beyond.min.css` is not working after it loads fine. How can i achieve the same solution provided in php's codeigniter? Thank you:
[Why can't I load js and css files on my pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35980873/why-cant-i-load-js-and-css-files-on-my-pages)

Comment: `base_url('assets/js/mycss.css')` ?

Comment: Any chance you mixed `css` and `js` directories up?

Comment: No itsjust ok even if my css file is in js directory.The link is the one which should be validly pointing to the correct file

Answer (score -1):

You could also use link_tag().

`<?= link_tag('assets/js/mycss.css') ?>` 
will give 
`<link href="http://yoursite.com/assets/js/mycss.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`

And make sure that base_url is specified in your config.php file